# Ocaml programming, example

Tags: ocaml

Need help!!

Define the function "Is_member," which the first parameter is the given matrix and the second parameter is x: int.
Check if element x is in the matrix1.

```
val Is_member: int list list -> int -> bool = <fun>
```

Example:

```
#let matrix1 = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]];;
#val matrix1 : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]

# Is_member matrix1 3;;
- : bool = true
```

Comment: You need to show us some code you tried, and explain what it does and ideally your theory for why it's not working. Otherwise we have nothing to go on. It's not useful (in my opinion) just to give you working code. You want to learn to fish yourself etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reduce your problem to `just fill blank spaces`:

```
# matrix1;;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]
# is_member 1 matrix1;;
- : bool = true
# let is_member x xs = List.____ (fun acc xs -> acc ____ (List.____ x xs)) false xs;;
val is_member : 'a -> 'a list list -> bool = <fun>
```

It will be easy for you now!

Comment: Thanks. But i need to get

val Is_member: int list list -> int -> bool = <fun>
Not

val is_member : 'a -> 'a list list -> bool = <fun>

Comment: You can swap arguments x and xs to get what you want. And polymorphic function which works for 'a will work for int